# PHP embedding array element inside string with curly braces

Tags: php

I would like to know what the advantage of using
curly braces is in the following context:

```
$world["foo"] = "Foo World!";
echo "Hello, {$world["foo"]}.\n";
```

is over the following:

```
$world["foo"] = "Foo World!";
echo "Hello, $world["foo"].\n";
```

In particular, how is it that the braces resolve any
possible ambiguity in this case (or similar cases)?

Comment: "Hello, {$world["foo"]}.\n" is semantically equivalent to "Hello, $world[foo].\n".  The manual explains this.

Comment: If one of the current given answers adequately answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 11):

Second example will not be parsed. So first is better:)

Anyway, I prefer to use

```
echo "Hello" . $world["foo"] . ".\n";
```

Because it is more easy to read to me.

Besides, there is another way:

```
$world["foo"] = "Foo World!";
echo "Hello, $world[foo].\n";
```

There no resaons to use one or another. you what you(or your team) like.

Comment: I absolutely detest the latter example. PHP has enough inconsistencies that we're forced to deal with.

Comment: OK, now I see. Of course, the inner double quote pair does not work because the second double quote escapes the first causing a syntax error. By enclosing the second and third double quote in braces this problem is avoided. (And I guess another solution would have been to simply replace the second and third double quote with single quotes). Thanks, John Goche

Comment: I know the braces { } could serve the purpose of grouping, but I did not know they would also cause the double quotes not to be escaped. Where can I read more about the use of { } inside strings (as opposed to used to delimit blocks of code)? Thanks, John Goche

Comment: Bit old, but as per the second example, PHP would interpret `foo` as a constant and throw an `undefined constant` error.

Comment: you sure? http://ideone.com/QOzqKM http://ideone.com/MEhhhv doesn't use constant even if thereis one

Answer (score 5):

See the other answers for the "echo" explanation, but if you're using heredoc, such as the following:

```
echo <<<EOHTML
<td>{$entity['name']}</td>
EOHTML;
```

You need the curly braces to properly use the associative array.

Comment: This is strange. Not sure whether your answer is really correct. The square brackets, i.e. the array indexing operator, has higher precedence than the dollar sign, so it seems to me that the curly braces should not be necessary. Correct? Not sure why the $ sign is not listed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php . Anyways, the follwoing works correctly: $a = array(1,2,3,4); echo <<<EOT     Hello, $a[0] !\n       EOT;

Comment: I didn't say that wouldn't work correctly.  I said for associative arrays, that's what you have to do.  Your example is not an associative array.

Comment: @JohnGoche His answer is correct if you use quote characters in the array keys. It's not about operator precedence; it has to do with string interpretation. See the manual about strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php